# DQl JOIN and WHERE

Tags: left-join, dql

I'm trying to get query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` u JOIN clientdetails d WHERE u.id = d.id AND d.staff_id =?
```

so I wrote DQL:

```
SELECT u FROM PswAdminBundle:User u JOIN PswAdminBundle:ClientDetails d WHERE d.staffRep=?0
```

but resulting query is

```
SELECT * FROM users u0_ INNER JOIN ClientDetails c1_ ON (c1_.staff_id = ?)
```

May it be because these two tables have 2 relations between them?

In users table I keep all users of app(clients and staff) records representing clients have relation one to one with table clientdetails using id from both tables. In clientdetails I have column staff_id that goes back to user table pointing on record representing staff user.

I'm trying to fetch all clients that are related to staff.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `WHERE d.staffRep=?0`? There is no staffRep in the other queries! Did you missed something?

Comment: staffRep and staff_id are same. Anyway I don't remember now exactly how but I fixed this problem already.

Comment: For the future, post the solution once you find it!